# C programming with libcurl. Received raw json data when print to screen with printf shows \uxxxx sequences. How to convert?

Tags: c, string, encoding, libcurl

With libcurl after a GET request I get raw JSON data response as a c string (char *data) that when printed to screen with printf I gives me the following output on screen:

```
screen output:
{"name":"\u0391\u03a0\u039f\u03a4\u0395\u039b\u0395\u03a3\u039c\u0391\u03a4\u0399\u039a\u039f\u03a4\u0397\u03a4\u0391"}
```

Apparently the data stored in the `char *data` is in c string notation a

```
"{\"name\":\"\\u0391\\u03a0\\u039f\\u03a4\\u0395\\u039b\\u0395\\u03a3\\u039c\\u0391\\u03a4\\u0399\\u039a\\u039f\\u03a4\\u0397\\u03a4\\u0391\"}"
```

I copied the screen output \uxxx sequences and tested in c code that if I `printf("\u0391\u03a0\u039f\u03a4\u0395\u039b\u0395\u03a3\u039c\u0391\u03a4\u0399\u039a\u039f\u03a4\u0397\u03a4\u0391";` it gives me on screen the expected `ΑΠΟΤΕΛΕΣΜΑΤΙΚΟΤΗΤΑ`

How do I convert the GET respone c string to a c string that when I print it to screen with printf, has the following output?:

```
screen output:
{"name":"ΑΠΟΤΕΛΕΣΜΑΤΙΚΟΤΗΤΑ"}
```

In essence I want to convert the memory data from a c string like

```
"{\"name\":\"\\u0391\\u03a0\\u039f\\u03a4\\u0395\\u039b\\u0395\\u03a3\\u039c\\u0391\\u03a4\\u0399\\u039a\\u039f\\u03a4\\u0397\\u03a4\\u0391\"}"
```

to a c string like

```
"{\"name\":\"\u0391\u03a0\u039f\u03a4\u0395\u039b\u0395\u03a3\u039c\u0391\u03a4\u0399\u039a\u039f\u03a4\u0397\u03a4\u0391\"}"
```

I can guess it has to do with character encoding but I can't find me a c library to do the conversion. After an hour of googling I gave up. So can anyone point me to a conversion library please?

(I'm using gcc compiler on ubuntu)

Comment: Yes they are unicode characters, expressed as printf escape sequence. Which os? You can convert the string to `char16_t *` string (or `wchar *`) using `strol` with base 16 for each element, then under windows select the codepage unicode and use `wprintf` to printout.

Comment: I use ubuntu and gcc compiler. Thanks.

Comment: It should work also with ubuntu. Use strol, with base 16, to convert the alpha string to an array of `wchar_t *` using strol with base 16, and printout with `wprintf`. The string must be zero terminated.

Comment: You should be able also to print is as `wprintf(L"%s", string);`, where `wchar_t *string="\u0391\u03a0\u039f\u03a4\u0395\u039b\u0395\u03a3\u039c\u0391\u03a4\u0399\u039a\u039f\u03a4\u0397\u03a4\u0391"`

Comment: I updated my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `locale.h`.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    printf("\u0391\u03a0\u039f\u03a4\u0395\u039b\u0395\u03a3\u039c\u0391\u03a4\u0399\u039a\u039f\u03a4\u0397\u03a4\u0391");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question to be more spesific of what I want to do.